# Group Policy, applocker, Application Control Policies

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2019

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBSxZ.png)

As an admin how can I prevent .exe generated specifically from ASP.NET web applications from getting blocked by AppLocker.

Context:
We are currently utilizing the local Active Directory on a Windows Server 2019 and have configured group policies on our domain controller. Our Application Control Policies are configured to block .exe.
The challenge we are facing is that AppLocker is also blocking ASP.NET web applications from running locally via Visual Studio & Visual Studio code as these web apps generate an .exe while runnuing locally. This is preventing developers from debugging code on their systems.

As an admin, I would want the policy to block .exe in general and also allow developers to debug code on their systems by allowing asp.net web application .exe.

Suggest the best alternative solution for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is probably not a good use case for AppLocker. Those environments tend to be more static.

That said, it should be possible to overcome this particular issue by creating an AppLocker publishing rule that allows code signed by your certificate.

This implies obtaining the certificate if you do not have one, and configured VS to sign the code on build, both prod and debug.

However you may find many other cases where this occurs, it needs to be tested for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an exclusion in your applocker for the exe. There is tool to automatically generate rules that might help with creating the exclusions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/run-the-automatically-generate-rules-wizard

For Defender Application Control:
https://webapp-wdac-wizard.azurewebsites.net/

You can also maybe sign the exe with a (code sign) certificate and then use that certificate in applocker to exclude, that's more future proof when you need allow exe in the future.

But I agree using applocker in a visual studio development environment is not ideal, it's more designed for creating secure workstations for end users.